# ¿Conocen alguna traducción para one-hot encoding?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática, matemáticas

Buenas, ¿conocen alguna traducción para [**one-hot encoding**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) en el contexto de aprendizaje automatizado o codificación en general?

Hasta ahora prefiero quedarme con el anglicismo pues no encontré una traducción y no me quiero arriesgar a introducir algo inapropiado yo mismo.

Pero si alguno de ustedes ya conoce una expresión en castellano para la técnica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> prefiero quedarme con el anglicismo pues no encontré una traducción y no me quiero arriesgar a introducir algo inapropiado

Es un criterio que comparto. Puedes entonces dejarlo como «**codificación *one-hot***» sin temor de llevar a confusión (como hacen por ejemplo en [la Wikipedia francesa](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encodage_one-hot)).

Y explicando en un aparte a qué te refieres, claro (código en el que cada palabra solo puede tener 1 bit activo cada vez, similar al código unario, ideal para identificar estados mediante máscaras, distancia de Hamming de 2... lo que veas adecuado).